Can't remove old kernels in AMI Linux
I'm running Amazon Linux release 2023.4.20240513 (Amazon Linux), and I need to remove old kernels,
I have these in /boot
vmlinuz-6.1.72-96.166.amzn2023.x86_64
vmlinuz-6.1.75-99.163.amzn2023.x86_64
vmlinuz-6.1.90-99.173.amzn2023.x86_64

On CentOS 7 I can use
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1 -y

However this does not work on AMI Linux,
dnf remove: error: unrecognized arguments: --oldkernels --count=1

Any ideas?

try:
dnf remove --oldinstallonly

you can modify /etc/dnf/dnf.conf line install_only_limit=x (where x=3 by default)
